# modifying the d3 force-directed graph example

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I'm new to javascript and D3.js, and I am trying to understand how it all works. I have been playing with the force-directed graph example here:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

What I want to do, is to change the JSON links from being array numbers to node names. I'm trying to visualize a small network topology, and I have the node neighbors all set up. Here is the JSON data I would like to use:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"stkbl0001","group":1},
    {"name":"stkbl0002","group":1},
    {"name":"stkbl0003","group":1},
    {"name":"stkbl0004","group":1},
    {"name":"stkbl0005","group":1}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":"stkbl0001","target":"stkbl0005","value":3},
    {"source":"stkbl0002","target":"stkbl0005","value":3},
    {"source":"stkbl0003","target":"stkbl0005","value":3},
    {"source":"stkbl0004","target":"stkbl0005","value":3}
  ]
```

I really don't know how to alter the D3 code to tie all this together. I fail to see the section where the array numbers is fetched and glued together as links. This is probably a stupid question, but it will help me a lot!

EDIT:

Here is the javascript code I have so far based on the input from Lars Kotthoff:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("mini.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  var nodeMap = {};
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { nodeMap[d.name] = d; });

  links.forEach(function(l) {
      l.source = nodeMap[l.source];
      l.target = nodeMap[l.target];
  })

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});
</script>
```

This fails at line 55 (nodes.forEach(function(d) { nodeMap[d.name] = d; });) with the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: nodes is not defined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This link](http://jsfiddle.net/2nhTD/) links to a working example based on the your example.

The critical code is placed just before initialization of force layout:

```
var nodeMap = {};

graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) { nodeMap[d.name] = d; });

graph.links.forEach(function(l) {
    l.source = nodeMap[l.source];
    l.target = nodeMap[l.target];
})

force.nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();
```

That way you will be able to use your data format in the same fashion as the original format is used (and many examples on the net follow that original format, so you will be able to adapt many of them to your format without problems).

*(json file is not used in my example, due to restrictions of jsfiddle; instead, function getData() is made to return the data; but this is not essential to your question; you can use this solution with json files too)*

Hope this helps.

Comment: This really helps a lot. Thank you for the nice jsfiddle as well. Great work! Unfortunately my reputation is too low to upvote.

Comment: Should have looked here a couple of hours of code experimentation ago!

Answer (score 0):

D3 provides two ways of specifying link source and target for the force layout. The first, used in the example you've linked to, is to provide the index of the node in the array of nodes. When the force layout is started, this is replaced with the reference to the actual node. The second is to provide the reference to the actual node explicitly.

To reference a node by name, you need something that allows you to resolve that reference. For example:

```
var nodeMap = {};
graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) { nodeMap[d.name] = d; });
```

Then you can do

```
graph.links.forEach(function(l) {
  l.source = nodeMap[l.source];
  l.target = nodeMap[l.target];
})
```

You can of course also use this to define `links` to start with:

```
"links":[
 {"source":nodeMap["stkbl0001"],"target":nodeMap["stkbl0005"],"value":3}
]
```

Comment: Thanks - this is definitively a step in the right direction. Unfortunately I'm unable to see where this code should be inserted in the example mentioned above. I have defined the links like you did at the bottom of your post. Where should I insert the `links.forEach(function(1)..` code?

Comment: If you define the variables as above, the code would go after the entire definition (`nodes` and `links`).

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't wrap my head around this. I have updated the question above, and added the error I get when I insert your code. I have probably done something wrong, but I am too noob to see it :-/

Comment: Right, in this case it actually needs to be `graph.nodes` and `graph.links`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This solved the case for a few nodes, but for several nodes I get some strange errors. This may be my fault, so I'll look into that. Thanks again!

Comment: I think there's an extra quotation mark after target on the last line.